# How to use different templates for collection without "root" node with rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, rabl

I'm working with Rabl for a while and just today I faced an interesting problem that I could't solve quite well..

So, I have a collection returned from GET ".../list/512/resources" and here is my sample rabl template that I used to return (without root) :

```
collection @resources
extends "api/v1/resources/_base"
```

=> { [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }

But, now I realize that I want to return different templates for each resource depending on their attributes.. so that's easy right?

```
node @resources => :resources do |resource|
  if resource.type == 'Document'
    partial('...', :object => resource)
  elsif @resource.type == 'Folder'
    partial('...', :object => resource)
  end
end
```

=> { resources: [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }

But ohh! Now I don't want that "resources" node there.. how should it be done? I tried something like:

```
array = []

@resources.each do |resource|
  if resource.type == 'Document'
    array << partial('...', :object => resource)
  elsif @resource.type == 'Folder'
    array << partial('...', :object => resource)
  end
end

collection array
```

but no success, it returns empty objects like => [ {}, {}, {} ]. Any idea how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the whole "@resources => :resources" and that should work (provided this is the content of resources/index.json.rabl and your controller sets @resources)

```
node do |resource|
  if resource.type == 'Document'
    partial('...', :object => resource)
  elsif @resource.type == 'Folder'
    partial('...', :object => resource)
  end
end
```

You might want to check https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers as a replacement for rabl. Given your use case it might be easier to use.

Comment: yeah, active model serializers rules! I've been using it since created that question and got frustrated with rabl